# Submenu position relative to Mainmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this menu that is active on the **first item of the main menu** (top):

[image]

The problem I have is that when the user click on the **middle, fourth or last main menu item**, the **submenu** now looks like this (getting out of everything):

[image]

Also, the **main menu will grow up** by the client, so there will be sixth, seventh, etc... so **I can´t just control with a class the items that are right now**...

Any ideas on how to come to a **css / jquery** solution about this? trying to follow the first image that is based on the design.

This is my markup:

```
                <ul id="mainmenu" class="clearfix">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a class="arrowdown" href="javascript:void(0)">ANSIEDAD</a>
                        <ul class="sublist">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Política</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Economía</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sociedad</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Medios</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Inmobiliario</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">PRETENSIÓN</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">HEDONISMO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">MATERIALISMO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">ARROGANCIA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu_search">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
ul#mainmenu{
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    width: 754px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    li{
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        background: #999999;
        margin-right: 4px;
        .round_corners();
        width: 140px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px 0px;
        position: relative;
        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 14px;
            &.arrowdown{
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                background: url('../img/sprites.png') no-repeat center -169px;
            }   
        }
        &#menu_search{
            background: url('../img/sprites.png') #000 2px 2px;
            width: 34px;
            height: 28px;
            padding: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            a{
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
        &.active{
            background: #000000;
        }
        &:hover{
            background: #000000;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        ul.sublist{
            position: absolute;
            width: 560px;
            top: 39px;
            left: 40px;
            li{
                float: left;
                margin-right: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                width: auto;
                padding: 1px 9px;
                background: #666666;
                a{
                    text-transform: none;
                }
                &.active{
                    background: #000000;
                }
                &:hover{
                    background: #000000;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this CSS working for you??

Comment: of course, why wouldn´t work?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the main menu a max-width. In this case I'd assume you want its maximum width to be 100%.

```
#mainmenu {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will not allow the main menu to exceed the page's width. You may encounter new problems with this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `max-width` will solve your problem. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/snikrs/c4xkR/1/)'s an example of how you can use max-width to keep the sub-menu in check.

Instead of breaking the sub-menu into two lines, you could probably try to shift the anchor point of the sub-menu to a more centralized location. Just my 2 cents.